# what is the use of signal processing in CT scans?

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to ask about the use of signal processing in CT scans ?
would be great if you suggest Book names or courses about it !
 thanks in advance !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform

Answer (score 1):

The C stands for 'computer', which should give you a strong hint that the answer is yes. The fundamental problem is the inverting the inherent radon transform that comes out of the measurement setup. There are other signal processing related issues too, like denoising, or image processing ones like feature detection and image segmentation.